# Java regex for dropping all characters before group

Tags: java, regex, scala

Can't figure out an efficient regex for:

```
whateverishere$$annofun$number$WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION$$number$
```

I want to remove all chars before `$$anonfun`, the `$$anonfun` itself and then eliminate the `$number$` groups.
I have this:

```
val index = fullName.indexOf("$$anonfun")
if (index != -1) {
  val str = fullName.substring(index + 9, fullName.length)
  str.replaceAll("[(\\$\\d+\\$)|(\\$)]", "")
} else {
  fullName.replaceAll("[(\\$\\d+\\$)]|(\\$)", "")
}
```

**Input**: whateverishere$$annofun$number$WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION$$number$

**Output**: WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION

Comment: Could you add the desired output corresponding to your input sample data?

Comment: Is it always the same number of $? Are $ ever inside WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION? Would it make more sense to split the string by $ and just grab the value at the 4th index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `"[^$]*\\$\\$[^$]*\\$[^$]*\\$|\\$\\$[^\\$]*\\$"`

```
String replaced = "whateverishere$$annofun$number$WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION$$number$"
            .replaceAll("[^$]*\\$\\$[^$]*\\$[^$]*\\$|\\$\\$[^\\$]*\\$",
                    "");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

but I'm not sure if it works like this in scala.

Comment: @flavian ok, than please update your question. I already updated the answer.

Comment: Could you please verify your question and post the string again that you use, because in your question the input ends with `$number$` and NOT `$$number$`. I can't reproduce the trailing `$`.

Comment: Hmm, if I execute the code in my answer the output is `WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION`. Sorry I can't reproduce the problem with the trailing `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work in scala but in Java you can wrap your interesting part in group and replace entire match with match from that group like.

```
"whateverishere$$annofun$number$WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION$number$"
  .replaceAll(
  "whateverishere\\$\\$annofun\\$number\\$(WHAT_NEEDS_EXTRACTION)\\$number\\$",
  "$1");
```

Comment: I can make this reegex more accurate if you provide actual input and expected output.